# How to get last friday or current friday date with respective of current week date in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery-ui, code-injection

I am adding 18 days for my current date and i want the last friday's date or next week friday's date with respective my current date

Here is my code

```
<?php
$created_date=$row['created_date'];  

$lengths = "+18 day";

$pickup_datess=strtotime($lengths ,strtotime($created_date));

$pickup_date1=date("Y-m-d",$pickup_datess);

$dates=strtotime("friday",strtotime($pickup_date1));

echo $dates; 
?>
```

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't understand what he wants? Can you give examples of how you want the output to be like?

Comment: i have an date and i am addding 18 days to it.for dat 18 th day it may be friday or some other day..if my 18th day ending on saturday i want that week fridays date otherwise if it is sunday or monday i want  that coming friday date

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve